# Creating system sounds

Tags: system, sound-theme

I'm trying to set up individual system sounds for ubuntu 15.04. I've read some instructions but they're a bit pithy for me.

Is there an app to add?

Answer (score 4):

Sound themes are located in `/usr/share/sounds/` , there should be 2 real themes "ubuntu" and "freedesktop".

Now copy one of those 2 directories to `~/.local/share/sounds/`, change its name and change the name in the `index.theme` file. If you are not that linux-savy to copy directories from root ownership to your home folder and change ownership to urself, you could alternatively download the freedesktop theme here: http://people.ubuntu.com/~dylanmccall/soundgallery/ and put it to `~/.local/share/sounds/`

Now you are good to go, exchange soundfiles with whatever you like. Make sure to keep the names of files and the .ogg format.

To change the soundtheme, install `dconf-editor`, open dconf-editor and change value `org.gnome.desktop.sound.theme-name` to the name of your new theme. Done.

You might need to logout and back in to activate the change in sound theme.

Have Fun.