# bah-boom, bah-boom noise won't cease!

Tags: boot, 18.04, sound

I installed a dual boot with Windows7, and **Ubuntu 18.04.02LTS** on my old desk top. All has been going well; I’ve progressed to the point of using Ubuntu about 90% of the time.

I notice **during the boot up procedure a "bah-boom, bah-boom" noise**, which I took as being similar to Windows chimes sound at boot up.  I also noticed receiving Ubuntu updates on a regular basis, which I would always install.
After complying to such a software upgrade notice and re-booting I heard the usual bah-boom noise, which usually stops after a few rounds; but this time it continues and is very ignoring.

Since this started after one of the updates and since it seems to be an extension of the boot up notification sound, I suspect the last update somehow corrupted my boot system. **I have re-booted many times and the noise continues.** I have run apt-get upgrade and it says my system is up to date. How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Try deleting the sound file as mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/a/817686/782567

Comment: After you type your password and press Enter does the sound still continue?

Comment: This was a problem 10 years ago for someone when switching user accounts: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=832749

Comment: The output of `inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80` might be useful. Do you see any log with the same timestamp of this sound issue? Check with `journalctl -xe -p err`